# Vertica admintools - unable to connect to database

Tags: vertica

I use admintools from Vertica in order to trigger Database Designer. However when I execute option "Run Database Designer" from admintools menu, I've been asked to provide a password. I use password for dbadmin user however it says "Unable to connect to database". With this password I am able to connect to the database from another main menu option "2. Connect to Database". I don't get why it fails for Database Designer? Do you have any idea?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found problem. I was using wrong password, not for pseudosuperuser user. According to doc: https://my.vertica.com/docs/7.1.x/HTML/Content/Authoring/AdministratorsGuide/Security/DBUsersAndPrivileges/DBDUSERRole.htm I should provide password for pseudosuperuser not for dbadmin.